# Divide $[0,2^{n+1}-1]$ into two $2^n$-sets with equal $0,1,\cdots,n$-th power sums

Tags: set-partition

I've learned that $[0,2^{n+1}-1]$ can be divided into two sets $A,B$, each with $2^n$ elements, such that
\begin{equation}
A^k:=\sum_{a\in A}a^k,\;\; B^k:=\sum_{b\in B}b^k,\;\; \text{and}\;\;A^k=B^k
\end{equation}
for all $k=0,1,\cdots,n$. In fact, one set has all elements with even number of $1$'s in their binary expression and the other set with odd number of $1$'s. For example $n=2$, we have $A=\{0,3,5,6\}$, $B=\{1,2,4,7\}$ and (define $0^0=1$)
\begin{equation}
4=4,\quad 0+3+5+6=1+2+4+7,\quad 0^2+3^2+5^2+6^2=1^2+2^2+4^2+7^2.
\end{equation}
Using induction, one can prove the above properties like this: for $n+1$, for $k=0,\cdots,n+1$,
\begin{align}
A'^k&=\sum_{a\in A}(a0)^k+\sum_{b\in B}(b1)^k=2^k\left(\sum_{a\in A}a^k+\sum_{b\in B}b^k\right)+\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\sum_{b\in B}\binom{k}{i}(2b)^i\\
&=2^k\left(\sum_{a\in A}a^k+\sum_{b\in B}b^k\right)+\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\sum_{b\in B}\binom{k}{i}(2a)^i=\sum_{a\in A}(a1)^k+\sum_{b\in B}(b0)^k=B'^k.
\end{align}
It is also simple to show their sums of the next power are not equal.

My question is, how to prove or disprove this is the only partition such that their sums of $k-$th power, for $k=0,\cdots,n$, are equal?

Comment: See _The Prouhet–Tarry–Escott problem and generalized Thue–Morse sequences_ https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/pages/journals/items/joc/content/vols/0007/0001/a005/

Comment: I tried to read it, especially example 3.2. Is there a simple way to prove the uniqueness of 2-letter alphabet?

Comment: @HaorenChen I am quite sure the partition you ask about is unique but haven't thought about how to prove it. Example 3.2 in my paper isn't meant to do that. I just thought the paper might be interesting for you since it does speak about the partition in your question.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks. It comes from a competition problem involving partition of $[0,15]$ and the judge solution uses congruence modulo 9, which is very special and technical. I am just curious if there exists a method to prove uniqueness for general $n$.